# как добавить background-image поверх <a href>

Tags: html, css, background-image

[image: изображение background-img наложенной на a]

Подскажите пожалуйста, не совсем понимаю как наложить картинку(галочка на скрине) на фон. Насколько понял задание, такие вещи нужно делать через background-image: url("...") и вроде-бы как через span...

Comment: Как задавать [вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Answer (score 0):

так как нет html и css объясню на пальцах.
В меню после Products вставляете любой элемент(div например или span)
в background-image указываете url и настраиваете width и height или можно символ ⇧ ⇩ вставить или похожий.
Делаете margin и padding под свой стиль.
Потом можно сделать :hover и менять атрибут url у картинки или символ на вверх/низ.